# Jinja TemplateSyntaxError with set

Tags: django, jinja2

I have some Jinja HTML:

```
{% for workout in workouts %}
    <div class="workout">
        <h1>{{ workout.name }}</h1>
        <div class="tags">
            <!-- TODO: Fix set error -->
            {% set tags = workout.tags.split(',') %}
            {% for tag in tags %}
                <p>{{ tag }}</p>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <p>
            {{ workout.description }}
        </p>
        <div class="actions">
            <button>Edit</button>
            <button>Start</button>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

However, the set assignment is raising a TemplateSyntaxError. The error page says it's expecting a {% endfor %}. The docs seem to agree with what I wrote so I'm not sure where the error is coming from. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you're using Jinja2?

Comment: Can't believe I missed that. Turns out Django offers Jinja but isn't its default syntax. Thanks!